# Create a link to a vector in the environment with paste

Tags: r, environment

I am needing to find a way to create a link to a vector in the R environment with paste() such that the link can be used in a function as below (which doesn't work):

```
 list1something <- list(c(1,2,3,4)
 name <- paste("list1", "something", sep ="")
 4 %in% name
```

Please help

Comment: How about `4 %in% get(name)[[1]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
list1something <- list(c(1,2,3,4))
name <- get(paste("list1", "something", sep =""))
4 %in% name[[1]]

> 4 %in% name[[1]]
[1] TRUE
```